# How can I map through an array of objects, remove one and set my state as the new array in react-native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, mapping

I have a list of checkboxes representing calendars. When a checkbox is clicked, the respective calendar is added to my state `checkedTaskList` as an array.

How can I map through this `checkedTaskList` array, and remove a calendar from it when it is unchecked? I wish to then set my state with the new array with the unchecked calendar removed.

STATE

```
const [checkedTaskList, setCheckedTaskList] = useState([]);
```

CALENDAR CHECKBOXES

```
<CheckBox_1 checked={() => setTaskCheked(calendar)} /> //Holidays
<CheckBox_1 checked={() => setTaskCheked(calendar)} /> //Birthdays
<CheckBox_1 checked={() => setTaskCheked(calendar)} /> //Events
```

setTaskCheked FUNCTION

```
const setTaskCheked = (calendar) => {
    if (checkedTaskList.length > 0) { //CHECK IF ARRAY IS EMPTY
     
      const tempCalendarList = checkedTaskList;
      tempCalendarList.map((cal) => {
        if (cal === calendar) { //CHECK IF SELECTED CALENDAR IS ALREADY IN checkedTaskList STATE
          const index = tempCalendarList.indexOf(cal);
          tempCalendarList.slice(index, 1);//REMOVED UNCHECKED CALAENDAR
          setCheckedTaskList(tempCalendarList);//SET STATE WITH NEW ARRAY WITH REMOVED CALENDAR
          
          
        }
        
      });
    } else {
      setCheckedTaskList([...checkedTaskList, calendar]);
    }
  };
```

HERE IS THE ENTIRE FILE

```
imports...

export default function AddCalendarModal(props) {
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState(false);
  const [checkedTaskList, setCheckedTaskList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
     if (checkedTaskList.length > 0) alert(checkedTaskList.length);
  }, [checkedTaskList]);

  const setTaskCheked = (calendar) => {
    if (checkedTaskList.length > 0) {
      if (c === true) {
        console.log(checkedTaskList.filter((cal) => cal != calendar));
        setCheckedTaskList(checkedTaskList.filter((cal) => cal != calendar));
      }
    } else {
      setCheckedTaskList([...checkedTaskList, calendar]);
    }
  };

  console.log("CHECKED TASKS" + JSON.stringify(checkedTaskList));
  console.log("CHEKCED TASKS LENGTH" + checkedTaskList.length);
  return (
    // <Modal visible={true} style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.clicked}>
        <Image source={require(".././assets/canceladdcalendar.png")} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={{ top: "10%" }}>
        <View style={styles.headertext}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            Manage Calendars
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, marginTop: "2%" }}>
            Select which calendars you’d like to see or add a new one.
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginTop: "5%" }}>
          {props.calendarData.map((calendar) => {
            return (
              <View key={calendar.summary} style={styles.calendaritem}>
                <CheckBox_1 checked={() => setTaskCheked(calendar)} />
                <View style={{ marginLeft: "3%" }}>
                  <Text>{calendar.summary}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          alignSelf: "center",
          position: "absolute",
          top: "50%",
        }}
      >
        <HearthButton
          backgroundcolor={"#1AA39B"}
          title={"Add a Calendar"}
          fontcolor={"white"}
          width={250}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.deletecalendar}>
          <Text style={{ color: "#1AA39B", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            Delete a Calendar
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
    
  );
}

styles...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=it) to get all *other* elements.

```
const setTaskCheked = (calendar) => {
    if (checkedTaskList.length > 0) {
      setCheckedTaskList(checkedTaskList.filter(cal => cal != calendar)
    } else {
      setCheckedTaskList([...checkedTaskList, calendar]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: this works great for adding and removing the checked calendars from the array ! but if I have 2 checked, and log "setCheckedTaskList" only one item is in the array though.

Answer (score 0):

Like Balastrong said, first use filter to remove the unchecked element, which you confirmed works.

What I'm assuming you're doing next is checking the array right after setting it, sorta like

```
setCheckedTaskList([...checkedTaskList, calendar]);
alert(checkedTaskList.length);
```

and this would show you the checkedTaskList's previous contents, as the call to set it is asynchronous.

EDIT:
After your edit, I'm wondering what the 'c === true' is, and what it does. I rewrote the setTaskChecked a bit, and it works for me. Here's my code

```
const setTaskChecked = (calendar) => {
    if (checkedTaskList.indexOf(calendar) === -1) {
      console.log(calendar + " is now in array");
      setCheckedTaskList([...checkedTaskList, calendar]);
    } else {
      setCheckedTaskList(checkedTaskList.filter((cal) => cal !== calendar));
      console.log(calendar + " removed from array");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(checkedTaskList.length);
  }, [checkedTaskList]);
```

Comment: this is still alerting 1 to me everytime....its almost like nothing is being pushed to the array after one item is selected...i think  setCheckedTaskList(checkedTaskList.filter(cal => cal != calendar) is running each time because its length is > 0 at that point so it never reaches the else command

Comment: Could you update your question with your entire code file?

Comment: I updated it no prob!